# Django App CSS working in Safari 3, not in Firefox 3

Tags: windows, django, firefox, safari

I'm working my way through a Django book and I just noticed something strange the other day.  The CSS code works just fine in Safari 3 (on Mac and Windows) but not in Firefox 3 (Windows).  I'm running the django dev web server and I can see the css file being called in the console when in Safari but not when using Firefox.  Any idea on what might be happening?

Comment: Have you tried to call the CSS file directly by URL on Firefox?

Comment: do you have a code sample or url?

Comment: It could be related to browser caching, but that's a stretch because I think Safari should also cache the same way as Firefox.  We just don't know enough information to really provide a good answer.

Comment: When I visit http://127.0.0.1:8000/site_media/style.css I do see the css file displayed.  When I use the View CSS option in the Firefox Developers Toolbar, it's obviously blank.

Comment: I thought about browser caching before but I've cleared all private data in Ff and still no dice.  I should note that IE7 also does not show CSS.  Google Chrome however does (which also used Webkit).

Comment: I didn't change anything in settings.py and I'm using some entries in urls.py to tell the app where the CSS files are:

site_media = os.path.join(
  os.path.dirname(__file__), 'site_media'
)

(r'^site_media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
      { 'document_root': site_media }),

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am an idiot....

This was the link to my css file in my head :

`<link rel="sytlesheet" href="/site_media/style.css" type="text/css" />`

Umm... that's not how you spell "stylesheet"!  Interesting that Webkit (Chrome and Safari) displayed the css even with the misspelling.  I figured it out when I went to the next chapter in the book and the jquery examples were working and the jquery.js file was in the same directory.  Something just wasn't adding up.

Sorry for the horrible question!

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing or do you have an extra slash in any of your paths?

E.g.

```
admin.site.root_path = 'admin'
```

Instead of

```
admin.site.root_path = '/admin/'
```

..in your urls.py

Or something similar in your settings.py?

Comment: I've left both MEDIA_ROOT and MEDIA_URL at their defaults (which is blank).  The info related to CSS in urls.py is posted in my last comment above.  I can't seem to figure out how to format the code in these comments.  Or can you even do that?  Sorry, first time poster here.